# Deleting part of a plan from extruded walls

Tags: edit-mode, extrude

I have a plan which I'm using to create wall for a building. This plan has 3 walls (1,2,3 on the picture below).

The wall #2 should be deleted in order to give space to a door (I've made this way to avoid `invisible mesh creation` as pointed out [here](https://github.com/MohitShridhar/gazebo_mesh_import/wiki)).

I'm new on blender an reading the basics says to use `delete` or `x` for doing that. None of them worked for me.

These wall are created using the extrude functionality (hotkey `e`).

Also removing the model in object mode ends up in deleting all walls (which is not what I want).

[image: image example]

Comment: "None of them worked for me" Did they really do nothing for you? I suspect they worked but not as you'd like them to. I can't follow the idea of the walls but maybe you want to make area marked with 2 empty, then add 2 loopcuts with Ctrl+R and delete the resulting face

Comment: I expressed myself wrong. They worked, but deleting faces not removes edges for instance. The wall idea is to extrude this plan on z-axis direction after completing 2-D plain.